# Good work-flow plugin available in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, jbpm, grails-2.0

I'm in search of good work flow plugin available for grails 2.0+ which is well documented and maintained. My application is called Training management System which for creating and maintaining  training's. on creation of training my workflow will start by sending email to trainer, participants and training owners.. and the process continues.

so please suggest me a good workflow plugins available .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GrailsFlow](http://www.grailsflow.org/) is a good one, regards to the grails integration (their website is sometimes very slow, though)

Answer (score 0):

Try Grails Activiti Plugin at http://code.google.com/p/grails-activiti-plugin/.

P/S: I'm creator of the plugin. Your feedback is very much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373599/grails-application-is-not-running-after-installing-grails-activiti-plugin
have a look at this question