# Grails application is not running after installing Grails activiti plugin

Tags: apache, tomcat, grails, grails-plugin, activiti

i have found grails activity plugin [Here](http://grails.org/plugin/activiti) and following this [document](http://code.google.com/p/grails-activiti-plugin/) to getting started with this plugin .

on running the application after installing the plugin i am getting following error

```
            | Running Grails application
            Activiti Process Engine with Spring Security Initialization ...
            Activiti Process Engine Initialization...

            Configuring Spring Security Core ...
            ... finished configuring Spring Security Core

            | Error 2012-07-07 14:02:45,500 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'transactionMana
            erPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tran
            actionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.fac
            ory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hi
            ernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resol
            e reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factor
            .BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.M
            taDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionF
            ctory (Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost" [90067-164])
            Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.Be
            nCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFac
            ory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to be
            n 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error cre
            ting bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialec
            ]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed
             nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.db
            p.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost" [90067-1
            4])
               Line | Method
            ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
            - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
            |   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
            |   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
            |   908 | run      in     ''
            ^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

            Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean propert
             'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve re
            erence to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExcepti
            n: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hib
            rnate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init
            ethod failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apac
            e.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localh
            st" [90067-164])
            ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
            - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
            |   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
            |   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
            |   908 | run      in     ''
            ^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

            Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean proper
            y 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot
            resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.
            actory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.sup
            ort.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConne
            tionFactory (Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost" [90067-164])
            ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
            - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
            |   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
            |   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
            |   908 | run      in     ''
            ^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

            Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean prope
            ty 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialect
            etector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData
             nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Conne
            tion refused: connect: localhost" [90067-164])
            ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
            - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
            |   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
            |   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
            |   908 | run      in     ''
            ^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

            Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.
            upport.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableCo
            nectionFactory (Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost" [90067-164])
            ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
            - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
            |   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
            |   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
            |   908 | run      in     ''
            ^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

            Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create Poolabl
            ConnectionFactory (Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost" [90067-164])
            ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
            - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
            |   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
            |   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
            |   908 | run      in     ''
            ^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

            Caused by SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost"
            90067-164])
            ->> 1549 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
            - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
            |   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
            |   1044 | getConnection in     ''
            |   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
            |   138 | run . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
            |   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
            |   908 | run . .  in     ''
            ^   662 | run      in java.lang.Thread

            Caused by JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost" [90067-164]
            ->> 329 | getJdbcSQLException in org.h2.message.DbException
            - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
            |   158 | get      in     ''
            |   397 | connectServer in org.h2.engine.SessionRemote
            |   287 | connectEmbeddedOrServer in     ''
            |   110 | <init> . in org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection
            |    94 | <init>   in     ''
            |    72 | connect  in org.h2.Driver
            |    38 | createConnection in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory
            |   582 | makeObject in org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory
            |   1556 | validateConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
            |   1545 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in     ''
            |   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
            |   1044 | getConnection in     ''
            |   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
            |   138 | run . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
            |   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
            |   908 | run . .  in     ''
            ^   662 | run      in java.lang.Thread

            Caused by ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
            ->> 351 | doConnect in java.net.PlainSocketImpl
            - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
            |   213 | connectToAddress in     ''
            |   200 | connect  in     ''
            |   366 | connect  in java.net.SocksSocketImpl
            |   529 | connect  in java.net.Socket
            |   119 | createSocket in org.h2.util.NetUtils
            |   100 | createSocket in     ''
            |    93 | initTransfer in org.h2.engine.SessionRemote
            |   393 | connectServer in     ''
            |   287 | connectEmbeddedOrServer in     ''
            |   110 | <init> . in org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection
            |    94 | <init>   in     ''
            |    72 | connect  in org.h2.Driver
            |    38 | createConnection in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory
            |   582 | makeObject in org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory
            |   1556 | validateConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
            |   1545 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in     ''
            |   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
            |   1044 | getConnection in     ''
            |   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
            |   138 | run . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
            |   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
            |   908 | run . .  in     ''
            ^   662 | run      in java.lang.Thread
```

what causes this error? how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for trying out the plugin.

You need to start H2 database as server mode prior to running the grails app. Start from 5.9 release, the plugin will run with in-memory H2 database.

Please post your future question to the discussion forum of the plugin at http://groups.google.com/group/grails-activiti-plugin to get faster response.

Best regards,
Chee Kin

Grails Activiti Plugin Creator

Answer (score 0):

java -jar YOUR h2 database jar, before you run your grails-app